# Compound circle object in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

Hello is it possible to draw an object like attached with cytoscape.js?

It is basically a large circle with two smaller ones. The smaller ones should not move individually but with the parent large circle?

Code would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried something yet? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is not compound node behaviour.  A child node is **within** its parent, and parent nodes are necessarily rectangular to accommodate the bounding box of the children.

You can implement whatever relationships and interactivity you want on elements, using the API.  Certainly the behaviour you describe is possible.

You may find these references useful:

- http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/position--dimensions/node.grabbable
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#collection/events/eles.on
- http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/collection-events